# resize jquery blinds

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I decided to use jquery blinds as my new photo gallery for my website.

http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/blinds/

I placed the html in my page and linked to the javascript and css. The gallery displays correctly in safari/firefox/chrome. However, while my vertical images look perfect my horizontal images are chopped off. I can only see part of the image. Is there somewhere in the js I can define the height and width? I am assuming that is the issue?

I'm pretty new to js, but I really like this jquery so I would like to figure it out! Also, I don't have the page Im currently working with online. However, if it's needed I can upload once I am home. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the size in css , eg:

```
li img {

 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 }
```

Comment: Awesome! Got the full image. Thank you!

Comment: No probs , can you mark the question as answered so I get my rep points :)